# NoSuchWindowException: no such window: target window already closed

Tags: java, selenium

I am running a test using selenium WebDriver and getting following error:

```
org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchWindowException: no such window: target window already closed
from unknown error: web view not found
  (Session info: chrome=50.0.2661.102)
```

The code I wrote is:

```
@Test
public void LogIn_Page() throws InterruptedException {

    driver.get(config.getApplicationUrl());

    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

    System.out.println("========== Login Test Start =========");

    login.loginAction("username", "password");
}


public class LogIn_Page {

    static WebDriver driver;

    @FindBy(how = How.CLASS_NAME, using = "button-login")
    public WebElement buttonLogin;

    @FindBy(how = How.CSS, using = "input[class='is-text']")
    public WebElement userName;

    @FindBy(how = How.NAME, using = "j_password")
    public WebElement passWord;

    @FindBy(how = How.CSS, using = "button[class='login__button']")
    public WebElement submit;

    @FindBy(how = How.ID, using = "login-popup")
    public WebElement loginPop;

    public LogIn_Page(WebDriver driver) {

        this.driver = driver;
    }

    public void loginAction(String UserName, String PassWord) {

        buttonLogin.click();
        userName.sendKeys(UserName);
        passWord.sendKeys(PassWord);
        submit.click();
    }
}
```

The test I want to do:

- Press the login button which creates a log in popup window
- Enter email, password,
- Press login.

The popup window appear, but the values of email and password not written (exception attached)

Comment: You're not showing any of the code you're using to switch to the other window.

Comment: Its the same window

Comment: >creates log in **popup window** ?